# using glob to return a list of folders in a given directory (without paths)

Tags: php

The function below returns all folders in a given directory down to multiple levels.

I only need one level depth though, just folders in the target directory, no subfolders.

Also the function returns the full path to the folder, I only want the folder name. I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

How can I modify the function to return only the folder names of the given directory? (not the full paths to each folder)

$myArray = get_dirs('../wp-content/themes/mytheme/images');

```
<?php
  function get_dirs( $path = '.' ){
    return glob( 
      '{' . 
        $path . '/*,'    . # Current Dir
        $path . '/*/*,'  . # One Level Down
        $path . '/*/*/*' . # Two Levels Down, etc.
      '}', GLOB_BRACE + GLOB_ONLYDIR );
  }
?>
```

btw, thanks to Doug for the original function help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/glob), I would suggest using the [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php) class.

```
function get_dirs($path = '.') {
    $dirs = array();

    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir() && !$file->isDot()) {
            $dirs[] = $file->getFilename();
        }
    }

    return $dirs;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, this looks great, but I'm having one issue. I'm running it from localhost but getting a fatal error...

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'DirectoryIterator::__construct(../wp-content/themes/mytheme/images) [<a href='directoryiterator.--construct'>directoryiterator.--construct</a>]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in C:\xampplite\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme\functions.php:436

Comment: Here's my caller.

$mydir = get_dirs('../wp-content/themes/mytheme/images');

Comment: Try `$mydir = get_dirs(realpath('../wp-content/themes/mytheme/images'));` instead.

Comment: ...or better yet: build and pass the absolute path to the function yourself. I don't know  your structure, but this could be as simple as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images'`.

Comment: I'd suggest a small fix in the function to use the global constant `__DIR__` instead of the string `"."` (which may result in a different location depending on how the OS may interpret it). As such, the function should read as follows: `function get_dirs($path = __DIR__) {`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want the current folder name and have a flat array in return, you can `extend` a `RecursiveFilterIterator` and simply collect a stack during RunTime when checking if you want to `accept()` it. Inside the `accept()` method you of course skip everything that has no child iterators attached, so you don't unnecessarily traverse through unneeded parts.

```
class DirectoryStackIterator extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    public static $stack = [];

    public function __construct( FilesystemIterator $iterator )
    {
        parent::__construct( $iterator );
    }

    public function getStack()
    {
        return self::$stack;
    }

    public function accept()
    {
        if ( $this->hasChildren() )
        {
            foreach ( $this->getChildren() as $c )
            {
                $dir = basename( $c->getPath() );
                $c->isDir()
                && ! in_array( $dir, self::$stack )
                    AND self::$stack[] = $dir;
            }
        }

        return $this->hasChildren();
    }
}
```

This makes it quite easy to define what exactly you want in return. `$c` is an instance of `SPLFileInfo`, so simply refer to that.

```
$iterator = new DirectoryStackIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
        __DIR__,
        FilesystemIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
        | FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
    )
);
```

Then we attach a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` (which extends `FilesystemIterator`, which then extends `DirectoryIterator` - to see what methods you got) and `SKIP_DOTS`, but follow symlinks. Remove the later one if you don't want that.

Finally we just traverse through our iterator iterators without actually doing anything. Keep in mind to use a semicolon (`;`) at the end to not trigger anything on the next line per accident.

```
foreach ( $iterator as $dir );
```

Collecting our custom stack then is quite easy:

```
var_dump( $iterator->getStack() );
```