# Locate - Finding directories only

Tags: php, linux

I have added my mounts to updatedb.conf, and want to be able to find these directories based on a reference. All I'm using at the moment is `locate T123123GB00` to get the results.

I will be using PHP but ideally do not wish to do a "is_dir(each_result)" against every value.

The file structure is like this though, which is where my problems come in.

```
/mnt/some/directory/T123123GB00/ (directory)
/mnt/some/directory/T123123GB00/SomeFile.docx (file)
/mnt/some/directory/T123123GB00/asdqwe.docx (file)
```

The results would return all three of these, how do I filter out the files so that I am left with one directory?

Thanks,

Harry

Comment: maybe this could shed some light --> [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1908319/1978142) and this [one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-loop-through-folders-with-phps-glob--net-11274) should help you also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$path = "./path/to/files";

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {

}
```

See the [DirectoryIterator Manual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) for more information.